# unlist() a list of 2 keeping both columns

Tags: r

I want to make a numeric vector that looks like this:

```
str(geneList)
 
Named num [1:12495] 4.57 4.51 4.42 4.14 3.88 ...
     - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12495] "4312" "8318" "10874" "55143" ...
```

My own dataframe contains 2 columns and I used the lapply function to convert it to a numeric vector:

```
str(mylist)
'data.frame':   9880 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ avg_log2FC: num  3.38 2.93 2.89 2.8 2.67 ...
 $ entrez    : chr  NA "6696" "8788" "3488" ...

mylist=lapply(mylist, as.numeric)

str(mylist)
    List of 2
     $ avg_log2FC: num [1:9880] 3.38 2.93 2.89 2.8 2.67 ...
     $ entrez    : num [1:9880] NA 6696 8788 3488 1028 ...
```

How do I unlist `mylist` so that it contains both the columns like shown in `geneList` above? If I use `mylist=unlist(lapply(mylist, as.numeric),recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)` it gives me something like below. Where is the 2nd column (entrez) going?:

```
    > str(mylist)
 Named num [1:19760] 3.38 2.93 2.89 2.8 2.67 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:19760] "avg_log2FC1" "avg_log2FC2" "avg_log2FC3" "avg_log2FC4" ...
```

```
dput(head(geneList)) c(4312` = 4.57261268231107, 8318 = 4.51459371540294, 10874 = 4.41821798112707, 55143 = 4.14407518193211, 55388 = 3.87625800905113, 991 = 3.67785700608222 )
```

Comment: `setNames(mylist[[1]], mylist[[2]])`

Comment: could you share you data using `dput(geneList)` or `dput(head(geneList))`?

Comment: `dput(head(geneList))`
`c(`4312` = 4.57261268231107, `8318` = 4.51459371540294, `10874` = 4.41821798112707, 
`55143` = 4.14407518193211, `55388` = 3.87625800905113, `991` = 3.67785700608222
)`

Comment: @gitanjaliroy I think Thomas misspoke. Can you do it instead with mylist? and edit your question to add it to that, not the comments please! :-)